# Using partial Composite Key in one-to-many Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have kind of following table structures for `Employee` and `Department`. The composite key of `Employee` has three columns - `EMP_ID`,`DEPT_ID`,`DEPT_CODE`
But the Department has only two columns which match the composite key of Employee - `DEPT_ID`,`DEPT_CODE`.

```
<class name="com.test.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
   <composite-id>
    <key-property column="EMP_ID" name="empId" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <key-property column="DEPT_ID" name="deptID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <key-property column="DEPT_CODE" name="deptID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
   </composite-id>
   <property column="EMP_NAME" name="empName" type="java.lang.String"/>
   <list name="departments" table="DEPARTMENT" fetch="select">
     <key>
    <column name="DEPT_ID"></column>
        <column name="DEPT_CODE"></column>
     </key>
     <index/>
     <one-to-many class="com.test.Department" />
   </list>
</class>

<class name="com.test.Department" table="DEPARTMENT">
   <composite-id>
      <key-property column="DEPT_ID" name="deptID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
      <key-property column="DEPT_CODE" name="deptID" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
   </composite-id>
   <property column="DEPT_NAME" name="deptName" type="java.lang.String"/>
</class>
```

Now I want to put a join on these two tables but it gives error saying primary key `EMP_ID` is not mapped. If I put the `EMP_ID` under "list departments key column" in `Employee` mapping xml, the application loads but does not have matching column in `Department` table.

So is there any way to deal with this. How to configure a `join`/`one-to-many mapping` in hibernate mapping file, when you have one table with a composite key and other table whose primary key is a subset of that composite key.

Comment: How does this join look like?

Comment: Another question: is it really really necessary to have all these composite keys?? NH as an ORM doesn't like composite keys very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "put a join"... Your problem sounds like it might be somewhat similar to this...

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985555

perhaps the problem is that your hql that is attempting a join (that you haven't provided) is not correct? If you can clarify your question you may get a better answer.